# Date variable is NULL while loading csv data into hive External table

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, sas

I am trying to load a SAS Dataset to Hive external table. For that, I have  converted SAS dataset into CSV file format first. In sas dataset, **Date variable (i.e as_of_dt)** contents shows this: 
`LENGTH=8 , FORMAT= DATE9. , INFORMAT=DATE9. , LABLE=as_of_dt`
And for converting SAS into CSV, I have used below code patch (i have used 'retain' statement before in sas so that the order of variables are maintained):

```
proc export data=input_SASdataset_for_csv_conv
        outfile=  "/mdl/myData/final_merged_table_201501.csv"
        dbms=csv
        replace;
        putnames=no;
run;
```

Till here (i.e till csv file creation), the Date variable is read correctly. But after this, when I am loading it into Hive External Table by using below command in HIVE, then the DATE variable (i.e as_of_dt) is getting assigned as NULL **:**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE final_merged_table_20151(as_of_dt DATE, client_cm_id STRING, cm11 BIGINT, cm_id BIGINT, corp_id BIGINT, iclic_id STRING, mkt_segment_cd STRING, product_type_cd STRING, rated_company_id STRING, recovery_amt DOUBLE, total_bal_amt DOUBLE, write_off_amt DOUBLE) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/mdl/myData';
```

Also, when i am using this command in hive `desc formatted final_merged_table_201501`, then I am getting following table parameters:

```
Table Parameters:
    COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE   false
    EXTERNAL                TRUE
    numFiles                0
    numRows                 -1
    rawDataSize             -1
    totalSize               0
    transient_lastDdlTime   1447151851
```

But even though it shows **numRows=-1**, still I am able to see data inside the table, by using hive command `SELECT * FROM final_merged_table_20151 limit 10;` , with Date variable (as_of_dt) stored as NULL.
Where might be the problem?

Comment: If the string is in the form 'YYYY-MM-DD', then a date value corresponding to that year/month/day is returned. If the string value does not match this format, then NULL will be returned in Hive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on madhu's comment you need to change the format on as_of_dt to yymmdd10.

You can do that with PROC DATASETS.  Here is an example:

```
data test;
   /*Test data with AS_OF_DT formatted date9. per your question*/
   format as_of_dt date9.;
   do as_of_dt=today() to today()+5;
      output;
   end;
run;

proc datasets lib=work nolist;
/*Modify Test Data Set and set format for AS_OF_DT variable*/
   modify test;
     attrib as_of_dt format=yymmdd10.;
   run;
quit;

/*Create CSV*/
proc export file="C:\temp\test.csv"
            data=test
            dbms=csv
            replace;
        putnames=no;
run;
```

If you open the CSV, you will see the date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it worked. Just one more question, still the Hive table parameters shows below result (even if there is one-to-one match between csv and hive table):   `Table Parameters:
    COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE   false
    EXTERNAL                TRUE
    numFiles                0
    numRows                 -1
    rawDataSize             -1
    totalSize               0
    transient_lastDdlTime   1447151851
`  
Is there some problem which still persists?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have any experience with Hive.  Perhaps you could ask this as a separate question and a Hive expert can answer for you.